# How to make a Google Home Graph request using a Service Account?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-home

I want to create a Desktop Application which would control Google Home Devices. For the past couple of hours I've been struggling with the Google Homegraph authentication process.

I created a Service Account and added the JSON file to the project's file. I am creating the credentials this way:

```
string[] Scopes = { HomeGraphServiceService.Scope.Homegraph }; 
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("ServiceCredentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                ServiceCred = ServiceAccountCredential.FromServiceAccountData(stream);

                GoogleCredential credentials = GoogleCredential.FromServiceAccountCredential(ServiceCred).CreateScoped(Scopes);

                var service = new HomeGraphServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
                    ApplicationName = "Test Application"
                });
            }
```

To create any request, I need to provide a `AgentUserId`. Any ID from the `ServiceCred` or the `service` itself (ApiKey) results in an exception with a code 400 error. The `credentials` (of type `GoogleCredential`) don't have any sort of Id that I can provide.

How to make a request with a Service Account to get devices from the Google Home Graph?

Another thing is, when I try to add the `HomeGraphServiceService.Scope.Homegraph` scope anywhere in the Google Project - API Playground, this Application - it results in a code 400 error - Invalid Scope on the OAuth page.

[image: Error 400 on Google OAuth Page]

Comment: A URL has parameters after the question mark.  For google api the id is a string that gets added to the URL.  See following for an example : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests

Comment: Which URL do you mean? The one in the Scopes? And does it apply to HomeGraph?

Comment: The one in the request.  The ID should be the same for any google request.

Comment: This authentication URL just won't work, even when I select it in the Google's OAuth Playground to get the AgentUserId, every other Authentication URL than the Home Graph's one works fine, so I'm not able to really do anything.

Comment: 1. what makes you think that Home graph api supports service accounts,

Comment: Here's the [Documentation for Google Home Graph](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/rpc/google.home.graph.v1) when it's said "the request must be authorized by a service account" for all the requests.